# Mpiexec difference between -n and -np?

Tags: mpi, mpiexec

I'm new to the MPI world and there is a question that is really annoying me. What's the real difference between -n and -np?

Comment: A lookup in the man page could help you https://linux.die.net/man/1/mpiexec

Comment: With most MPI implementations those two options are synonyms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The MPI standard does not specify how MPI ranks are started and leaves it to the particular implementation to provide a mechanism for that. It only *recommends* (see [Section 8.8](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report/node228.htm#Node228) of the MPI 3.1 standard for details) that a launcher (if at all necessary) called `mpiexec` is provided and `-n #procs` is among the accepted methods to specify the initial number of MPI processes. Therefore, the question as posed makes no sense unless you specify exactly which MPI implementation you are using. As I already said in my comment, with most implementations both options are synonymous.

Note that some MPI implementations can integrate with batch scheduling systems such as Slurm, Torque, etc., and those might provide their own mechanisms to start an MPI job. For example, Open MPI provides the `orterun` process launcher, symlinked as `mpirun` and `mpiexec`, which understands both `-n` and `-np` options. When running within a Slurm job though, `srun` is used instead and it only understands `-n` (it actually has a completely different set of options).